# Mediawiki Upload disabled when disabling php functions

Tags: php, security, file-upload, mediawiki

I have a mediaiwki installation on which upload worked perfectly. However, I disabled some php functions from `php.ini` for security reasons:

```
disable_functions = passthru,system,popen,proc_open,parse_ini_file,show_source,chdir,ini_set,ini_get,diskfreespace,disk_total_space,php_uname,posix_geteuid,exec,shell_exec,posix_getpwuid,chmod
```

which resulted in mediawiki upload being automatically disabled.

Does anybody know which disabled function is used for the file uploading process? I tried re-enabling `popen` and `proc_open` but they don't seem to be related.

I know I could solve it by trying to enable each function, but I thought it would be good to have such a question on SO.

Comment: `chmod` could couse the problem. The usual upload scripts use `chmod` to fix the uploaded files permissions.

Comment: @Fracsi: Tried it (along with `popen` and `proc_open` without success :\

Comment: Check mediawiki prerequisites. It could use `ini_set, ini_get, chdir, parse_ini_file` as well.

Answer (score 1):

i'm sorry to say that but you should remove these functions from your forbidden list : `parse_ini_file,chdir,ini_get,ini_set,chmod`

to get mediawiki upload work fine